# Should glob, with GLOB_MARK, append / to symlink-to-directory results?

Tags: c, posix, glob, language-lawyer

The `glob` function has a `GLOB_MARK` flag that's specified to append a slash to results which are directories:

> GLOB_MARK
>
> Each pathname that is a directory that matches pattern shall have a `<slash>` appended.

(Source: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/glob.html)

However, as far as I can tell, no further details are provided on how this feature is supposed to work. In particular, if a result is not a directory itself, but is a symbolic link to a directory, should a slash be appended? The glibc implementation does this.

I know this is a hard question to answer given the terseness of the standard for `glob`, so good answers will be ones that cite historical practice, historical standards or documentation other than POSIX that might further specify the behavior of `glob`, etc. Answers which bring up reasons why one behavior or the other is more useful would also be interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my own team's unofficial research branch: ;-)

> glob(3) first appeared in bsd4.3-reno in 1989 and it appended '/' after directory symlinks with GLOB_MARK
>
> http://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=4.3BSD-Reno/src/lib/libc/gen/glob.c
>
> (glob2 uses stat, not lstat on the pathbuf)
>
> solaris has a glob with copyright comment from 1985
>
> that one adds '/' to symlink paths as well